# int is never equal to the value set

Tags: java, android, int

As above, when I click a the british flag button on my app, it is meant to change langNumber to 0, so that a specific sound is played by wolvesfid. However, the value is never set to 0, but instead something else which causes the wrong sound to be played. in fact, even when I remove all code from my button, and leave only the break, the value still ends up changing, despite it playing the correct sound prior to pressing the button.

Relevant code:

```
case R.id.britishflagid:
        langNumber = 0;
        MediaPlayer mpB = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,
                R.raw.langselect);
        mpB.start();

case R.id.wolvesfid:

        wolvesFThread.postDelayed(wolvesFRunnable, 0);

        if (langNumber > 0.1) {
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,
                    R.raw.wolvesstartd);
            mp.start();
        } else {
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,
                    R.raw.wolvesstartn);
            mp.start();
        }

        adCount += 1;
        wolvesFStart = 1;

        break;

Runnable wolvesFRunnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        wolvesFTimer();
    }
};

    public void wolvesFTimer() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(35000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (langNumber > 0.1) {
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,
                R.raw.wolvesfriendlytwod);
        mp.start();
    } else {
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,
                R.raw.wolvesfriendlytwon);
        mp.start();
    }

    try {
        Thread.sleep(15000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    MediaPlayer ls = MediaPlayer
            .create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.langselect);
    ls.start();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (langNumber == 0) {
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,
                R.raw.wolvesfriendlyspawn);
        mp.start();
    }
    if (langNumber == 1) {
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,
                R.raw.wolvesfriendlyspawnd);
        mp.start();
    }
    wolvesFStart = 0;
}
```

Basically, why does the code not recognise `langNumber == 0` ? All help appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you are certainly setting langNumber to 0? Did you log to check if your code entering in the right switch case? May be it is not entering 

case R.id.britishflagid:
        langNumber = 0;
        MediaPlayer mpB = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,
                R.raw.langselect);
        mpB.start();

so this is never set to 0.

Comment: I just checked with log, and it's definitely using the flag. I'm also pretty sure it is given it's playing the sound when I press it.

Comment: Solved. Always use "break;" in your switch case, guys. Thanks for the help, though! :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `break` statement in the `case block`

```
case R.id.britishflagid:
        langNumber = 0;
        MediaPlayer mpB = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,
                R.raw.langselect);
        mpB.start();
        break;
```